# How to rewrite method in idiomatic Ruby way

Tags: ruby

I have a method that sums the diagonals of an array of arrays (grid). It works as follows (assuming the middle has value of 1 so that is why 1 is removed at the end...):

```
def sum_diagonals(grid)
  sum = 0
  0.upto(grid.size-1) do |i|
    sum += grid[i][i]
    sum += grid[i][grid.size-1-i]
  end
  sum-1
end
```

Now I want to rewrite this in a more Ruby way with a code block and on one line. I tried things as the following:

```
def sum_diagonals(grid)
  (0..grid.size-1).inject(0) {|acc, i| acc += grid[i][i] + grid[i][grid-1-i] }
end
```

but it says no implicit conversion of FixNum into Array. I know the 1 or middle value which is counted double will be counted twice. But ignoring that I do want to rewrite the method. Can someone tell me how to do this elegantly?

Comment: A grid class with enumerators for its diagonals would probably be more Ruby like

Comment: @Stefan could you explain how to make a grid class with enumerators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are trying to index an array with an array so change

`(0..grid.size-1).inject(0) {|acc, i| acc += grid[i][i] + grid[i][grid-1-i] }`

to:

`(0..grid.size-1).inject(0) {|acc, i| acc += grid[i][i] + grid[i][grid.size-1-i] }`

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_diagonals2(grid)
  grid.each_index.inject{|acc, i| acc + grid[i][i] + grid[i][-1 - i]}
end
```

Comment: Yes, `acc +=..` not needed. It is (assignment) implicit.. +1

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. Gives half size.

Comment: The `-1-i` instead of `size -1-i` is very nice too.